# "Restart at 1" resets paragraph formatting of Heading style

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

To illustrate my problem:

> 1. Create new document
> 2. Enter three lines of text: "H1", "H2", "H3".
> 3. Select all lines.
>
>    - Click style "Heading 2".
>    - Select numbering, such as "Number Aligning: Left".
>    - Add `2 ch` left indentation and `2 ch` hanging.
>    - Update style "Heading 2" to match selection.
> 4. Right click on the numbering of the third line and select "Restart from 1"
> 5. Observe that the indentation and hanging is broken.
> 6. Clicking "Heading 2" will not fix it.

I have multiple Level 1 headings in my document and multiple Level 2 headings under each Level 1 heading. I want to restart numbering for each Level 2 heading when any Level 1 heading ends, while assuring that all the styles of Level 2 headings are consistent-- with the same indentation and hanging. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by defining a new multilevel list style, formatting the Level 2 list within the dialog, and updating Header 2 style to match selection.

Comment: Bit42 you can post your edit as a separate answer because it is different from mine.  I'll test your solution in a few days and if it works I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Note that if you have a VBA subroutine called "RestartNumbering", this will be run when you try to "Restart at 1".

For example if my code changes the indent or font size in "Sub RestartNumbering()", then this will always happen when you restart numbering from the pop-up menu, and no formatting will prevent this.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant.